# Should questions pertaining to tax law be asked here or on money SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions pertaining to tax law be asked here or on money SE? I guess questions for businesses should be asked here, but I am unsure regarding questions about individuals facing taxes.

Answer (score 2):

I think if an accountant could answer the question, money.SE probably has more expertise than here.

If it's more a question within the scope of administrative law or statutory/regulatory interpretation, deference, etc. this site would have more expertise. As far as I can tell, we don't have any tax law specialists here.

It's a hard line to draw without first seeing the specific question.

Comment: Thanks, here is an example of a question for which I am unsure: http://law.stackexchange.com/q/8165/31

Comment: It's so hard to know... it's kind of like, if you get an answer here, then it was probably a good question for here, but if you don't, then it probably wasn't. I know that's not really helpful to you. My impression of the site so far is that we don't have the tax law experts here that would be able to answer such a specific question.

Comment: Eh, anything law is on-topic, but just because it's on-topic doesn't mean you'll necessarily get an answer to your question :/